# Scan dynamodb Array inside List Map from Lambda - Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm looking to scan Dynamodb Table with a `form_id` which is inside a List -> Map. Currently it returns 0.

My DB looks like this

```
{
  "id": {
    "S": "117f2e-XXX-XXXXXXX"
  },
"forms": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "form_id": {
            "S": "117f2ef66e6b"
          }, 
        "db_id": {
            "S": "2f40c0300000"
          }, 
        }
      },
       {
        "M": {
          "form_id": {
            "S": "XXXXXXXXXX"
          }, 
        "db_id": {
            "S": "YYYYYYYYYY"
          }, 
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My Query is

```
let params = {
    TableName: "My_Table",
    FilterExpression: "contains(forms, :query)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":query": {
            "L": [{
                "M": {
                    "form_id": {
                        "S": "117f2ef66e6b"
                    },
                }
            }]
        }
    },
}
const data = await dynamodb.scan(params).promise();
```

But it does not work. I wanted to search for `form_id` and return that array object with other data inside that eg: `db_id`
Can  anyone help what's the error?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there are 2 ways to do this: 1, you must know the whole map object you're looking for (in your case both the `form_id` and `db_id` values), then you can search the list for the map: `ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':query': { 'M': { 'form_id': { 'S', '...' }, 'db_id': { 'S': '...' }}}}`. That will work. If you only know part of the map's values, then you will have to return all the potential results and filter them in your code. This won't "cost" any more read capacity units than filtering in DDB, though will no doubt be slower than if the filtering was done in DDB.

Comment: @404 So, in option 1, if I know the rest of the data, I should list every value in the expression values? If I missed something, it would return nothing?

In Option 2, If I have 5 list items in `forms`, I need to get every item in the array, then filter in Javascript? That sounds good too. What would the expression looks like then? (ps: only some rows have this `forms` field, not all rows)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Also, does option 1 work if we use any other expression instead of CONTAINS, eg: `IN` keyword? Because I'm scanning the data to get another data from the object.  eg: I have form ID to get DB ID, to get DB ID, I actually need to find it using Form ID itself.

Comment: *"So, in option 1, if I know the rest of the data, I should list every value in the expression values? If I missed something, it would return nothing?"* - correct. *"In Option 2, If I have 5 list items in forms, I need to get every item in the array, then filter in Javascript?"* - you'd have to get every item in the table (assuming you can't filter it down so a subset), then in your JS code you check if any have that value of interest. I don't believe the IN keyword will work here, though I may be wrong.

Comment: Another option, but this is only if you know how many items the array can hold, would be to do something like this: `FilterExpression: "forms[0].form_id = :f_id OR forms[1].form_id = :f_id OR forms[2].form_id = :f_id OR forms[3].form_id = :f_id"`, assuming you can know with some certainty that `forms` won't contain more than 4 items. So if you know it won't contain more than *n* items, and that number is not too large, just make it check each index manually.

Comment: @404 How can I get the complete array if the array exists? eg: If I have 500 items, the form_id is present in 5 of them. In that case can I get that 5 array? If yes, what would be the expression for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233145/discussion-between-surjith-s-m-and-404).